# Determining a surjective or injective function where variables denote cardinality

Tags: functions

If I get a function between $\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ :

$f(m, n) = |m|-|n|$

How should I work out whether or not the function is injective or surjective?

As far as I know, the vertical lines indicate cardinality, and the cardinality of these variables will always be the same, therefore making$f(m,n) = 0$ in all cases ( and therefore making the function neither injective or surjective). Is this correct?

(I know the example is trivial I just want to know how to approach a similar function which uses cardinality (or what I think uses cardinality))

Comment: It's not cardinality. It's absolute value, that is $|x|=\max\{x,-x\}$.

Comment: The function is also not from $\Bbb Z$ to $\Bbb Z$, but from $\Bbb Z^2$ to $\Bbb Z$.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, $f$ is a function between $\Bbb Z\times Z\to\Bbb Z$, and the vertical bars indicate absolute value.

Although it could be argued that natural numbers (= nonnegative integers) might be viewed as cardinal numbers, it does not make sense to see an arbitrary **integer** as a cardinality: cardinality denotes the number of elements in a set, and a set cannot have a negative number of elements. Similarly concepts such as any single rational number, real number or complex number do not have a cardinality.

---

The function $f$ is **injective** if it sends every input to a unique value: no two distinct inputs get send to the same value. So to determine if $f$ is injective, you need to find out if there are two *distinct inputs* $(m,n),(m',n')\in \Bbb Z\times Z$ such that $f$ will send them to the same value. Suppose we consider $(m,n)=(3,-1)$, then

$$f(3,-1)=\ \big|3\big|\ -\ \big|-1\big|\ =3-1=2.$$

Can you find some values $(m',n')$ such that $f(m',n')=2$ but such that also $m'\neq m$ or $n'\neq n$?

The function $f$ is **surjective** if every element of the target set gets reached by some input. So to determine if $f$ is surjective, we need to take an arbitrary element $x\in\Bbb Z$ and find some $(m,n)\in\Bbb Z\times Z$ such that $f(m,n)=x$.

Comment: Ah I see. So in effect the function is from integers to natural numbers? I did think it was a bit strange 'to see an arbitrary integer as a cardinality' but I thought it was some kind of trick question. Now it makes much more sense. Thank you.

Comment: @JimothyBucksworth No, it is from pairs of integers to integers. The source and target of the function are of vital importance if you want to determine injectivity and surjectivity.

Comment: For example, the function $f(x)=x^2$ with source $\Bbb R$ and as target $\Bbb R$ is not surjective (there is no real number $x$ such that $x^2=-1$ for example). On the other hand, if the target is the set $\Bbb R_{\geq 0}$ of nonnegative reals, then the function is surjective. Similar things are true for injectivity: $f$ is not injective, but if the source contains only nonnegative reals, then $f$ does become injective.

Comment: Sorry I meant from natural numbers to integers. If m and n have to be positive numbers aren't they essentially natural numbers?

Comment: @JimothyBucksworth No, the $m$ and $n$ you plug in are integers. The absolute bars $|m|$ and $|n|$ transform these integers into natural numbers. If $m$ and $n$ are natural numbers, it does not really make sense to use absolute bars, since the numbers are already absolute to begin with.

Comment: As an additional comment, even then it has to be a function from **pairs of** integers to integers, since your input consists of **two** values. Compare: $g: \Bbb Z\to\Bbb Z$ and $h:\Bbb Z\times \Bbb Z\to\Bbb Z$, with $g(n)= 2n$ and $h(m,n)=2m+n$. The first is a function from integers to integers, the second is from pairs of integers to integers.

Comment: I understand that it is **pairs** of integers to an integers, but thanks for clarifying that **in effect** it is from a **pair** of natural numbers to integers

Comment: @JimothyBucksworth You get the same range if you only can plug in natural numbers. However, it can have an impact on injectivity of the function. Consider instead the function $f(m,n)=2^{|m|}\cdot 3^{|n|}$. It is injective if its source is pairs of natural numbers, but not if its source is pairs of integers.